# Is there a Model.objects.update_or_create() for AWS Appsync using VTL?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-appsync, vtl

I'm using `$util.autoId()` and would like to know if there is a pattern to do an `update_or_create()` (similar to the Django one) using VTL or if I should link the Resolver to a Lambda and do the logic in there?

Comment: What data source type are you using?

Comment: @RohanDeshpande DynamoDB Tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Amazon DynamoDB UpdateItem operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) to perform an update-else-create operation. We have published an end-to-end sample that includes an [example AWS AppSync resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html#create-an-updatepost-mutation-ddb-updateitem) that illustrates this pattern.

Comment: I've read the tutorial on the resolver in the AWS docs, and there is nothing in the custom UpdateItem resolver that creates an item if that particular ID does not exist. Is this possible?

I want to have a single API call that either creates (PutItem) or updates (UpdateItem) a new post, depending on whether the ID already exists.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? When using Appsync's `update` function, I get `DynamoDB:ConditionalCheckFailedException` when trying to update a non-existent resource... the generated resolver does not appear to support create-or-update logic.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new resource in the AppSync console the following resolver is generated for the "updateYOUR_MODEL" mutation

just remove the last part:

```
 "condition": {
    "expression": "attribute_exists(#id)",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#id": "id",
    },
  }
```